# Newlines in description of imported csv in Outlook Calander

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-outlook-2010, csv, newlines

I have exported a list of birthdays from excel to csv. 
Now I want to import them in Outlook as calander items.
Everything works fine exept I can't do newlines in the desciption.
I've already tried to use `\n`, `\r\n`, `<br>` and make a newline in the excel cell (which creates in the csv file also `\n`).

Anybody got an idea?
The csv file looks like this:

```
name,date,description
Test,15-9-2014,Test\r\nNewline\r\nAnother
Test2,16-9-2014,Test\r\nNewline\r\nAnother
Test3,17-9-2014,Test\r\nNewline\r\nAnother
```

Comment: isn't it usually \n rather than /n ?

Comment: Sorry, you'r right. I used `\n`

Comment: So was the incorrect slash the issue or are you still having this problem?

Comment: Still having the problem

Comment: When you use the `\n` does it print it in the description, or remove it and just not add a new line?  Have you tried `\r\n`?

Comment: It printed it in the description. No i haven't tried it yet. I'm going to try it this evening.

Comment: Didn't work either... :( Same result: "Test\r\nNewline\r\nAnother" in the description without any newlines.

Comment: How about replacing the errors with a find+replace and inserting the ascii char for newline? alt+0010

Comment: Nope, it will just remove the other words. So the description become: "Test".

Comment: Take a look at this [kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816)